# Should we split the "output" tag into "software-output" and "hardware-output"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have just finished writing a tag wiki excerpt for [output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/output) (If you have the priviliges, please review my edit :) ) and said that it should be only for questions about hardware output ("Can I use a VGA monitor?") not software output ("How  do you write to a file?").

That got me thinking, should we split [output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/output) into [software-output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-output) and [hardware-output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-output)?

"How can I access the GPIO from python" would be [software-output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-output), but "Can I use headphones with a built-in microphone in the audio socket?" would be [hardware-output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-output).

I am saying this mainly becuase questions about software output can be hugely different to questions about hardware output.

Answer (score 2):

No.  I do not think any of these tags are useful.

Unlike related tags such as [hdmi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdmi) or [audio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio), I expect it will be very rare for anyone to search for these tags, to subscribe to them, or even to read the associated tag wiki.

The tag wiki page for (some topic) X is where you go if you want to know "what is X."  E.g. if I want to know what Debian is I will go to the [debian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) tag wiki etc.  Similarly it makes sense to ask "What is HDMI" or "What is a GPU" but not "What is software output."

**Edit** for completeness, this is how I would tag those questions:

- How can I access the GPIO from python?
  [gpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpio) [python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) and maybe [peripherals](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peripherals)
- Can I use headphones with a built-in microphone in the audio socket?
  [headphones](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphones) [microphone](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microphone) [audio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) [accessories](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessories)

I think these tags give enough information by themselves.  Adding any of the "output" tags would not make them any easier to find.

Comment: So you're saying get rid of them all?

Comment: @ACarter, ideally yes, though I expect [tag:output] would reappear in new users' questions (after the public launch), whereas [tag:software-output] and [tag:hardware-output] would not.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose a new user isn't exactly going to go looking for them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think this would be a good.

Although perhaps just [output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/output) and [hardware-output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-output) would be good enough, otherwise the output tag would continuously be proposed as [software-output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-output) may be easy to miss.